# Dialog box is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have very simple code. I want to show dialog box whenever someone clicks hyperlink.

```
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
  <a id='theLink' href="#">Common Questions</a>

      <div id="dialogform1"  title="Common Questions" style ="display:none">

       <p> this is question 1 </p>

</div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function()  

     {

    $("#theLink").click(function(e) {

       $('#dialogform1').dialog("open"); 

    });

  });

    </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

However , this does not open dialog box with the div content declared earlier.  I don't know what am I doing wrong here ?  I have spent quite few hours to find why is it happening but can't seem to find it.  It needs another eyes to look at problem.

Thank you for taking time and answering the question.

Comment: Do you need to include the jQuery UI library also?

Comment: and may I ask why downvote this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code:

Refer [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <a href="#" id='theLink' name="theLink">Common Questions</a>
        <div id="dialogform1" style="display:none" title="Common Questions">
            <p>this is question 1</p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#theLink").click(function (e) {
                $('#dialogform1').dialog();
                $('#dialogform1').dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the following:

```
- include jQuery UI -- JS & CSS
- initialize the dialog widget before trying to open
```

Ref:

```
- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
```

**UPDATE**

[**WORKING JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Qx6FP/1/show/)

[**PLAY WITH CODE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Qx6FP/1/)

Once you've included `jQuery UI` the following code is what you need:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#dialogform1').dialog({autoOpen:false});

    $("#theLink").click(function(e) {

        $('#dialogform1').dialog("open");

    });

});
```

All the files you need to include are here:

```
- http://code.jquery.com/
```

Comment: i am sorry , could you please point me to which files/URL/Links I have to include. I am quite new to jQuery and don't know this stuff.

Comment: Actually the blog now has links to the files you need (http://blog.jqueryui.com/) (it used to be at the bottom of the page @ jqueryui.com)... don't point to the beta files, so the current post you'll need is [jQuery UI 1.10.4](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2014/01/jquery-ui-1-10-4/)